# Problems on migrating Parse.com app to AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, parse-platform, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 machine with Ubuntu installed on it. On the machine, I have installed Node.js, MongoDB, and Github version of Parse Server.

I have created a database called euro. In this database, I've created a user using this code:

```
> use euro
switched to db euro
> db.createUser(
... {
... user: 'username',
... pwd: 'password',
... roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db:'euro' } ]
... }
... )
```

Before migrating the app, I have noticed that in AWS EC2 Instances Managment page, you can see 2 IPs addresses: Public IP and a Private IP, so I used the Public IP.

In the Parse.com settings, I've clicked at the Migrate button, and entered this address:

```
mongodb://username:password@<ipaddress>:27017/euro
```

and below the address field, it was written `No reachable servers`.

What can I do in order to solve it and to migrate the app to my EC2 Instance?

**EDIT #1:**

I have restarted my AWS server, so my Public IP address has been changed. I've tried to change my connection string to the new IP using this address:

```
mongodb://username:password@<ipaddress>:27017/euro
```

But suddenly it shows `No reachable servers`.

What should I do in order to solve this problem? I want to migrate it as soon as possible.

**EDIT #2:**

I've checked this command `sudo netstat -pan | grep mongod` to check on which IP it is listening and I got this output:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      10945/mongod 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:45406         ESTABLISHED 10945/mongod 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     28614    10945/mongod        /tmp/mongodb-2
```

Is it listening on the Public IP? Private IP? localhost?

Comment: Did you open port 27017 in the security group?

Comment: I opened the port, and now when I'm trying to migrate it, it shows this message `We strongly suggest you enable SSL on your database and use the URL option 'ssl=true'`. I tried to add `?ssl=true` at the end of the connection string, but now it shows again `No reachable servers`. What should I do?

Comment: You probably need to enable SSL on the server side before attempting to connect over SSL. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

Comment: Did you try using a self sign ssl certificate or buying one?

Comment: Try normal  telnet diagnostic. I.e. telnet  ipaddress 27017 . if you get a connection refused error,  then ssh into your ec2 instance, and do the same things. if that failed as well, check your mongodb config

Comment: Please follow the diagnostic step shown here in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351889/mongodb-is-not-installed-properly-on-ubuntu-11-04-in-amazon-ec2?rq=1

Comment: I checked it using `sudo netstat -pan | grep mongod` and I've updated the question. Please take a look on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using MongoDB [guide](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134080/91067) answer.

The problem was some warnings that I got when I've started the server. Apperently It had prevented Parse.com from connecting to my MongoDB.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.11
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-04-01T07:28:10.926+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>
```

I wasn't able to solve it because I used this command `$ service mongod restart` without root permission. I was supposed to use this command `$ sudo service mongod restart`.